# How to change date format from string to dd/mm/yy on iOS?

Tags: ios, string, date, format

So i am parsing an xml file and display on screen the dates that i parse.
The dates are like : Thu , 31 May 2012 20:43:54 GMT.
How can i convert the date to this format : dd/mm/yy ?
i dont need the time.

---

Well it crashes.
I tried :

```
NSString *date = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"date"];

//changing dates format
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];

NSString *dateText = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate]];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `NSDateFormatter`

For example:

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];

    NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:yourString];
```

See http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns for dateformat patterns

Comment: And if then i want to use the date as a string how do i convert the dd/mm/yyyy to a string? I mean this format : dd/mm/yyyy as a string and not as a NSDate

Comment: You can use `stringFromDate` in the same way as `dateFromString`(which is applied above). So check out the `stringFromDate`. I hope this answers the question.

Comment: use this: NSMutableString *timeString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[DateFormat stringFromDate:dateToConvert]];

Answer (score 5):

The idea is to use `NSDateFormatter` to get a date from your input time string, then use a new dateformatter to get whatever new time string you want from the date.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss Z"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:theDateString];
[dateFormatter release];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy"];
NSString *newDateString = [dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:date];
[dateFormatter2 release];
```

Comment: mmm ok this one doesnt crash BUT it displays nothing on screen. I just see a blank space in my cell where i am trying to display it. Any ideas!?

Comment: If you input time string is look like this "Thu , 31 May 2012 20:43:54 GMT", the date format is `EEE , d MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss Z`. Be careful date format need to match your input time string.

Comment: When i print the first format on console i get:
2012-06-04 10:25:10.575 TAB RSS[1272:f803] the object value is:Fri, 01 Jun 2012 15:52:00 GMT
When i prin the second format:
2012-06-04 10:25:10.577 TAB RSS[1272:f803] the object value is:(null)

Comment: Do you have whitespace after the weekday and before the comma? Since I see two different time formats on the your question and comment.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively for the second part You can use NSDateComponents.
after:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss Z"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:theDateString];
[dateFormatter release];

//Get NSComponents from date object..

[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@",dateComponent.date,dateComponent.month,dateComponent.year];
```